# Are Linux distro differ only by user-land?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, docker, user-interface

I recently came across Docker and the concept where-in the Linux docker container re-use the same   kernel of the Host machine.

Does it mean, each linux distribution like Debian (Deb1 to Deb11), Redhat, Ubuntu etc... all are differed only basis on the end-look (UI to user) and the pkg's installed with them and their versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest difference between distributions is usually only in the userspace, but the kernel can differ too. It's still the same Linux so there isn't a big room for differences, but you can of course have different versions on different distributions, each distribution usually has a different [kernel config](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Kernel/Configuration), different set of modules available etc. but in the end it's the same kernel with the same API.

IMHO the biggest difference with kernel across distribution is the version they offer and whether they offer regular updates or stay on a stable version.

Comment: Surly, the kernel differ , the free kernel, the non-free kernel and the linux-libre kernel...

Comment: Linux libre is a fork of Linux and I think you can remove all the non free firmware just using the config (but I might be wrong here). I probably should've specified that by kernel I mean only Linux, kernel could also mean BSD or Hurd, but that's a different story.

Comment: For some distros like RHEL/CentOS backports (both of features and security fixes) and enterprise features also make some amount of difference with the vanilla kernel code base disregarding the build config, which makes the kernel part of the distro more or less unique.

Comment: Yes, but it still is Linux, just a different "version", or to be more specific mix of multiple upstream versions. Still not a big difference from userspace point of view.